# How to get first value of WrappedArray in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I grouped by few columns and am getting `WrappedArray` out of these cols as you can see in schema. How do I get rid of them so I can proceed to next step and do an `orderBy`?

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM 
  parquet.`parquet/20171009121227/rels/*.parquet`")
```

Getting a dataFrame:

```
val final_df = groupedBy_DF.select(
  groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev)").as("rel"),
  groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev2)").as("rel2"))
```

then printing the schema gives us: `final_df.printSchema`

```
|-- rel: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
|-- rel2: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

Sample current output:

[image]

I am trying to convert to this:

```
 |-- rel: double (nullable = true)
 |-- rel2: double (nullable = true)
```

Desired example output (from the picture above):

```
-1.0,0.0
-1.0,0.0
```

Comment: collect_list would certainly create a WrappedArray. Can you provide sample output as how you want the ouput dataframe be ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I added the desired output

Comment: what if you have more that one row for the group? i.e. what if you have [WrappedArray(-1.0, 1.0), WrappedArray(0.0, 0.0)]? how do you plan to transform this to final ouput dataframe?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan hi, yes i just showed 2 rows. one column is rev1 and the other is rev2. There are mutiple rows. i just took screen shot in black for just 2 records/rows

Comment: you didn't understand my question. [WrappedArray(-1.0), WrappedArray(0.0)] is reduced to -1.0,0.0 but how would you reduce to output if collect_list created  [WrappedArray(-1.0, 1.0), WrappedArray(0.0, 0.0)]?

Comment: I think what Ramesh is asking is, what happens in the scenario that rel AND rel2 has multiple items inside the wrappedarray?

Comment: @ayplam,@RameshMaharajan,
that wont be an issue, there will only be one value in both rel and rel2

Comment: @dedpo then why do yo use `collect_list`? If there is only 1 item, use `first`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where `collect_list` will always only return one value, use `first` instead. Then there is no need to handle the issue of having an Array. Note that this should be done during the `groupBy` step.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val final_df = df.groupBy(...)
  .agg(first($"relev").as("rel"), 
       first($"relev2").as("rel2"))
```

Comment: how come this doesn't work in spark class, it works through `REPL..agg(first($"relev").as("rel") ` especially. agg doesn't seem to compile and throwing error

Comment: @dedpo What is the error? To perform an `agg` you first need to use `groupBy`, hence, I mentioned it need to be done during that step. Also, make sure the `import spark.implicits._` is done correctly and that the parentheses are correct (in your comment you are missing a `)`).

Comment: To anyone in the future, grouping/agg like above might need to use `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`  so, `df.groupBy(...)
  .agg(col(first($"relev")).as("rel")`. An alternative to this would be use DataFrame and use reparition and then sortwithPartitions

Answer (score 1):

Try `col(x).getItem`:

```
groupedBy_DF.select(
    groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev)").as("rel"),
    groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev2)").as("rel2")
).withColumn("rel_0", col("rel").getItem(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try split

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val final_df = groupedBy_DF.select(
  groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev)").as("rel"),
  groupedBy_DF("collect_list(relev2)").as("rel2"))
  .withColumn("rel",split("rel",","))
```